# Software package for calculation of intersections of polyhedra in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, computational-geometry

There are many good packages for calculating the intersection of polygons. I have found the GPC library useful.

I would like to compute intersections of polyhedra (piecewise linear boundaries) in 3D. Are there any good libraries in C/C++ for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I've found [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html#part_VII), but I haven't tried it out yet.